# regex code to avoid some strings

Tags: regex, mongodb

I am working on ipython and mongodb project and I have problem with regular expression.
In short, I have a document like this in db

```
{ 'aa':'foo </FOO >' }
```

my question is that how the regexcode should be to print just 'foo' only and avoid '<'/FOO> ?

So far, I've done like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([match, project, unwind])
```

This code works well as I expected. However, I want to filter some string in documents, so I want to add

```
match2 = {"$match" : {"aa" : / regex code here/}}
```

And then, `db.collection.aggregate([match, project, unwind, match2])`

But it returns none. How to fix it?

Comment: This is far too broad, can you clarify your question a bit? I.e. programming language, which DB, etc. How did the strings get there in the first place?

Comment: Ok then. I will update it to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not support `$regex` in projections yet. There is an open JIRA ticket which will address this at some point, though:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947

So you cannot extract a string from a field using MongoDB at this point unless you go for a [$substring](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) based approach which, of course, is a little less powerful.

However, you can filter all your documents to only return elements with `"foo"` in it like so:

```
match2 = {"$match" : {"aa" : /foo/}}
```

And then you can use some client side code to extract the matching parts, e.g. in JavaScript:

```
var regEx = /(foo)/;
doc.aa = regEx.exec(doc.aa)[1]; // return first matching group
```